Dual nic server with open client http port unreachable
I am setting up a poe switch connected to my ubuntu server 20.04. I am running an amd 5700 with some generic parts in a minipc that is being used as an nvr. I have a internet facing nic, eno1, where my ui would be bound for the nvr and a nic, enp3s0, with isc-dhcp-server running. I need a docker container running on this server to have access from the container to the cameras on enp3s0 that are provided ips by the dhcp.(not including established connection).
I have created a netplan config, dhcp config, and set the interface in the isc config. I can ping the cameras and see the open http and rtsp ports. I can also see the leases issued for the cameras. When i try to curl or try to connect via either one, it is unreachable from the host and container.
In addition to the above, i have enabled ipv4 forwarding, allowed all traffic from one nic to the other with iptables just to test, but it was copy paste from some post.
Not sure why i can see the leases and ports, but not reach them
